# Trying to create a printable web page in octobercms

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, octobercms

Hi I am trying to create a printable page from data send by a form in octobercms
I have created a plugin component which I have called PrintPageForm

```
<?php namespace Acme\PrintPage\Components;

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Input;
class PrintPageForm extends ComponentBase
{
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        // TODO: Implement componentDetails() method.
        return
        [
            'name' => 'Print Page Form',
            'description' => 'Detail page print form'
        ];
    }
    public function onHandleForm()
    {
        $var =
            [
                'overview' => Input::get('print_overview'),
                'photos' => Input::get('print_photos')
            ];
```

I have this in the default htm file

```
<form action="/print" data-request-data="printpageform::onHandleForm" data-request-validate data-request-flash accept-charset="utf-8" class="form ajax-form">
 <h3 class="sub-heading">Print Details</h3>
  <p>To build a printer friendly formatted page, please select from the options shown below:</p>
     <ul class="print-section">
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" value="1" name="print_overview" id="print_overview">
             <label class="checkbox-label period" for="print_overview">Overview: Summary and key features alongside a photo of the property.</label>
         </li>
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" value="1" name="print_photos" id="print_photos">
             <label class="checkbox-label period" for="print_photos">Photos: Photo gallery of the property.</label>
         </li>
                  </ul>
     <input type="hidden" name="print" value="1">
     <button class="btn button-large one-third palm-one-whole" type="submit" rel="print" >Print</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to access the value of print_overview and print_photo values in my print view page but can not figure out how to access these values I can see these values being passed in Debugbar as follows "request_query
array:2 [ "print_overview" => "1" "print" => "1" ]" and in my view file I have

```
{%if "print_overview" == "1" %}
 {{ 'checked' }}
  {% else %}
  {{ 'Not Checked' }}
  {% endif %}
```

but it does seem to matter what the value of print_overview is the page only echos out Not Checked I'm in a rut that I can't figure out any thoughts would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: an alternative could be to generate a PDF with https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-dynamicpdf

Answer (score 2):

Couple of pointers. When rendering a form in Twig, you should use either [the `{{ form_open() }}` or `{{ form_ajax() }}` tags](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-form)

Secondly, you can access the request data via the `post()` function in your component class; and you pass it to your view (the component partial) through the `page` property. So, your handler would like something like:

```
public function onHandleForm()
{
    // Pass the variables to the view renderer
    $this->page['print_overview'] = (bool) post('print_overview');
    $this->page['print'] = (bool) post('print');

    // Return a partial response http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/update-partials#pushing-updates
    return ['#view-response-element' => $this->makePartial('@response')]; 
}
```

While your response.htm partial file would look something like this:

```
{% if print_overview %}
    "checked"
{% else %}
    "not checked"
{% endif %}
```

As a note, if you are using the `{% macro %}` tags, these do not have access to the local scope of the partial file, i.e. they do not have access to the variables provided to the view. Any evaluation done within `{% macro %}` tags needs to be based on variables passed to it.

Comment: Thank you Luke I'll try this out I've been going round in circle with this one

Comment: I getting an error  PrintPageForm does not contain method of makePartial

Answer (score 2):

The best strategy for printing I find is to use JavaScript:

```
<!-- Link to print -->
<p><a href="javascript:printInvoice()">Print this invoice</a></p>

<!-- Invoice printer -->
<script type="text/template" id="invoiceTemplateContents">
    Printable contents go in here
</script>

<!-- Script -->
<script>
    function printInvoice() {
       var printWindow = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=950,height=500,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0')
       printWindow.document.write($('#invoiceTemplateContents').html())
       printWindow.document.close()
       printWindow.focus()
       printWindow.print()
       printWindow.close()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Samuel I've been watching some of you tutorials and have been trying to figure out the best method to achieve the desired result I'll give this a go and let you know how I do